# wp_mail not sending emails in HTML

Tags: wordpress

I want to send html emails from wordpress and I have performed following to make it working. It includes
setting content as html
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
Allowing html tags in strip tag (not working with or without it)

```
<code>
$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags()); 
</code>
```

in it included all tags including  (comma separated i.e `'<div>,<link>..'`).

I am not able to generate the html email correctly.  In the postman email log I see html section such as div, H3 but  of style css file is not present there (it is removed by wp_mail).

```
$emailTo = 'abc@abc.com' ;
$subject = 'Updated about the process';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$headers []= 'From: xyz@xyz.com';
$body = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"     
content="text/html charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>';
$body=$body.'<link rel="stylesheet" href="normal.css">';
$body=$body.$'<div class="flrow lar_overflow">';
$body=$body.'<div class="flexooa lar-line-header">Recent History</div>';
$body=$body.'<div class="flexiia lar-line-header"></div>';
$body=$body.'<div class="flexooa lar-line-header hlast"></div>';
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
$wpse_excerpt = strip_tags($wpse_excerpt, wpse_allowedtags());
wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

So how to avoid removal of the css file tag  from generated html content.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below 2 stesps:

1. HTML template should have inline stylesheet only. Don't use any external CSS path.
2. By default WordPress mails are considered as plain text so change it to HTML type using headers parameter or using hook.

Check this URL: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Check content : The default content type is ‘text/plain’ which does not allow using HTML. You can set the content type of the email either by using the ‘wp_mail_content_type‘ filter ( see example below), or by including a header like “Content-type: text/html”. Be careful to reset ‘wp_mail_content_type’ back to ‘text/plain’ after you send your message, though, because failing to do so could lead to unexpected problems with e-mails from WP or plugins/themes.

Reference URL to set it by hook: (Check the example at below URL)
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_content_type/

It will definitely works! Good Luck.

Comment: None of this works. Inline styles are getting stripped off (despite I have defined not to strip them). I am already using content type HTML as shown in example.